# wp_redirect() doesn't work

Tags: redirect, headers, wp-redirect

I am inserting a piece of code to my website that includes a redirect statement. Everything works fine except the `wp_redirect();`. The following warning message appears.

```
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/xyz.com/b14_32999707/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-styles.php:350) in /home/xyz.com/b14_32999707/htdocs/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1416
```

Following is line 1416 of the mentioned file.

```
$x_redirect_by = apply_filters( 'x_redirect_by', $x_redirect_by, $status, $location );
if ( is_string( $x_redirect_by ) ) {
    header( "X-Redirect-By: $x_redirect_by" ); //Line 1416
}

header( "Location: $location", true, $status );

return true;
```

Tried each and every solution available on the web but nothing works except the JavaScript redirect which I don't want to use.
Even a very simple php code like the following doesn't work.

```
<?php
if(...){
  wp_redirect('http://www.my-site.com/my-page/');
  exit();
}
```

Comment: _where_ are you calling `wp_redirect`? You can't redirect if the server has sent output to the browser, even a single space character will send the HTTP headers, and HTTP headers can only be sent once. Once they are sent it is too late. This is one of the reasons it is impossible to use `wp_redirect` inside blocks widgets and shortcodes, because it is too late. You can either output, or you can redirect, once you begin output, redirection becomes impossible.

Comment: Yeah I am inserting this code using a plugin through shortcode. There are some more contents created through Elementor and at the end this shortcode.

Comment: I have set a local server using Wamp and created a simple wordpress website where I test various stuff for learning purposes. I inserted this code there, and it works, but not on the online website I am managing.

Comment: you can't do redirects in a shortcode. It's possible you have some sort of output buffering that prevented output from happening that is happening locally but not on production, but if you want to do a redirect on an event, a shortcode/widget is the worst place to put it, it's just too late in the page load

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not *what* you are doing, but *when* you are doing it.

When your browser requests a webpage, that webpage arrives with a set of HTTP headers, followed by a HTTP body that contains the HTML. Redirection is done via a HTTP header. The moment you `echo`, or `printf` or send any form of HTML, or even blank space PHP will send HTTP headers telling the browser to expect a webpage, then it will start sending the HTTP body. When this happens your opportunity to redirect has gone, and any attempt to send a HTTP header will give you the error in your question.

For this reason, you cannot trigger http redirects in shortcodes, widgets, templates, etc.

Instead, do it earlier, before output begins, preferably in a hook, e.g.

```php
add_action( 'init', 'asmat_maybe_redirect' );
function asmat_maybe_redirect() : void {
    if ( ... ) {
        wp_redirect( 'http://www.my-site.com/my-page/' );
        exit();
    }
}
```

Additionally, if that redirect is to somewhere else on the *same* site, use `wp_safe_redirect` instead. But whatever you do, it **must** happen early *before* any output occurs.